# Split work between writing output from .exe and reading the output

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a simple .exe downloaded from the apple app store. It gives real-time updates on crypto prices and their percentage change. I am extracting percentage changes of bitcoin.

I am using a subprocess to extract the output. I am storing the output into four separate text files, then I'm reading the text from the files, extracting the data I need and saving it into a pandas dataframe.

Additionally, I have a 60 second timeout for each .exe run, and I read the file after 70 seconds. I truncate the file by removing its content, and by the time the next file has output in it, I'll read that file also, then truncate and repeat.

I want to know how to split the work between saving the output into a textfile and reading the content then truncate it. For example, I am running a simple thread that should run the .exe and extract the output with `write_truncate_output`. However, I only have `append_output_executable` running.

Here's my script:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call as x
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Process

cmd = [r'/Applications/CryptoManiac.app/Contents/MacOS/CryptoManiac']
text_file = ['bitcoin1.txt','bitcoin2.txt','bitcoin3.txt','bitcoin4.txt']

def append_output_executable(cmd):
    while True:
        i = '1234'
        for num in i:
            try: #append the .exe output to multiple files 
                with open(os.devnull, 'rb') as DEVNULL, open('bitcoin{}.txt'.format(num), 'ab') as f:
                    x(cmd,  stdout=f, stderr=STDOUT, timeout=60)
                
            except:
                pass  


def write_truncate_output(text):
    while True:
        time.sleep(70)
        with open(text, 'r+') as f:
            data = f.read()
            f.truncate(0)
            #read and truncate after reading the data
    
            #filter and format
        percentage=re.findall(r'\bpercent_change_24h:\s.*', data)
        value= [x.split(':')[1] for x in percentage]
        key = [x.split(':')[0] for x in percentage]

        #store in dictionary
        percent_dict = defaultdict(list)

        for ke, val in zip(key, value):
            percent_dict[ke].append(val)
            percent_dict['file'].append(text)

        percent_frame = pd.DataFrame(percent_dict)
    
        print(percent_frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for text in text_file:
        execute_process = Process(target = append_output_executable, args=(cmd,))
        output_process = Process(target = write_truncate_output, args=(text,))
        execute_process.start()
        execute_process.join()
        output_process.start()
        output_process.join()
```

this stil just runs the first function.

Comment: frankly, I don't undestand why to run it in seprated threads/processes. It can make only problems to synhronize data. System decides when processes are exactly executed and they can run in different moments when you expect. I would do all at once after getting from external program. Besides it can work little faster if you don't use files but keep all in memory.

Comment: you use threads in wrong way - `target` needs  function's name without `()` and arguments - and later it will use `()` to start it - `Thread(target=append_output_executable, args=(cmd,))`. Current code runs `append_output_executable(cmd)` at once - and when you exit this program then it tried to create `Thread()`

Comment: in example with process you have another problem - you assing process to `p2` inside loop but you starts `p2.start()` after loop. But `p2` can keep only one value - so it keep only last process, and finally you runs only last `p2`. You should run `p2.start()` inside loop or you should keep processes on list and later run `for`-loop to run `.start()` on every element on this list.

Comment: as for me it could be faster to execute `check_call` once and laster write the same output to 4 files.

Comment: @furas I am running these separately because when I have them all in one function, I cannot get past the executable running. So I still cannot get it to read the output. I have updated my script with `args` also, but the same issue occurs. Perhaps it's because I am running  ```append_output_executable``` within a `while` loop, but I want it to run 24/7, and when I set a `timeout` it would close it. So the `while` loop continues it after closing.

Comment: did you remove `()` from `target=`?  Did you use `start()` inside `for`-loop? Maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables.

Comment: frankly, as for me you should do all calculations directly in this `while`-loop

Comment: BTW: your code in `write_truncate_output` would also needs some loop - at this moment it runs it only once so you may not see differences.

Comment: BTW: thread can't send result to main process so using `return percent_frame` is useless. But threads share memory so it would need to use `global` to send data to main process. And you could also use `global` to send data from one thread to anothers without using files.

Comment: @furas I have updated it as you mentioned; it's just as you mentioned `write_truncate_output` would only do it once. I have tried wrapping it all under a `while True` however, it does not seem to work. I'll look into how to wrap alternative loops for it - additionally, I'll look into `global` also

Comment: you have to run `while`-loop inside function `write_truncate_output` - similar to `while`-loop inside `append_output_executable`. But I would use global variable `running = True` and `while running:` - this way you can later set `running = False` to stop loops in functions.

Comment: @furas I do not think the issue is with the `while` loop. I have updated the post, but I think the issue lies in `execute_process` and `output_process`. I put everything in a loop, and it would just run `output_process` once. Then keep running `execute_process`, the same happens if I put `execute_process` outside the `for` loop. However, when that happens `output_process` runs first and then `execute_process`.

Comment: @furas the `append_output_executable ` has stronger precedence over `write_truncate_output`. Not sure why this happens, but it seems that `write_truncate_output` gets put on hold after it runs once.

Comment: you run it in wrong way - you run `append_output_executable` inside `for`-loop so it runs 4 times the same functiona - and all 4 functions do the same. You should run it before `for`-loop. And don't use `join()` inside loop becaues `join()` waits for end of function - and this blocks other code,. You should first `start()` all processes and later `join()`

Comment: another mistake - don't use `return` inside `while`-loop. This way you run it only once.

Comment: problem is that you have few different mistakes - when you repair one mistake then it still doesn't work because you have other mistakes.

Comment: @furas LIFESAVER! fixed the issues. Also, back to your first comment. What is your suggestion with loading it into memory? I could not find a way to accomplish this. The difficulty I had was storing the output from `check_call` into an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answer resolve all your problems because you have few mistakes in program - when you repair one mistake then it still doesn't work because there are other mistakes.

---

First:

`target` in `Thread` and `Process` needs function's name without `()` and arguments - (this is called `callback`) - and later (when you use `.start()` ) it will use `()` to run this function inside new `Thread` or `Process`

```
Thread(target=append_output_executable, args=(cmd,))

Process(target=append_output_executable, args=(cmd,))
```

---

Second:

`Thread` and `Process` runs this function only once so it needs `while`-loop to run all time. And it can't use `return` because it ends function.

---

Third:

`.join()` block code because it waits for end of `Thread` or `Process` and it should be used after starting all threads/processes - usually it is used at the end of program when you want to stop all threads/processes

---

And small suggestion(s):

You could use global `running = True` and inside function `while running` - and later you can set `running = False` to stop loops in function (and finish functions)

---

Code could look like this

```
# ... other imports ...
from threading import Thread

def append_output_executable(cmd):
    while running:
        # ... code ... (without `return`)

def write_truncate_output(text):
    while running:
        # ... code ... (without `return`)
         
# --- main ---

# global variables

running = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # --- create and start ---
    
    t0 = Thread(target=append_output_executable, args=(cmd,))
    t0.start()
        
    other_threads = []
   
    for text in text_file:
        t = Thread(target=write_truncate_output, args=(text,))
        t.start()
        other_threads.append(t)
        
    # ... other code ...
    
    # --- at the end of program ---
    
    running = False
    
    # --- wait for end of functions ---
    
    t0.join()
    for t in other_threads:
        t.join()
```

Exactly the same is with `Process`

(I keep the same names of variables to show that all is the same)

**EDIT**

Processes doesn't share memory so it would need to use queue to send information `running` to processes. So this version need changes.

```
# ... other imports ...
from multiprocessing import Process

def append_output_executable(cmd):
    while running:
        # ... code ... (without `return`)

def write_truncate_output(text):
    while running:
        # ... code ... (without `return`)

# --- main ---

# global variables

running = True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # --- create and start ---

    t0 = Process(target=append_output_executable, args=(cmd,))
    t0.start()

    other_threads = []

    for text in text_file:
        t = Process(target=write_truncate_output, args=(text,))
        t.start()
        other_threads.append(t)

    # ... other code ...

    # --- at the end of program ---

    running = False

    # --- wait for end of functions ---

    t0.join()
    for t in other_threads:
        t.join()
```